# excel comparison using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I am trying to compare two different excel sheets using node.js . There are two different sheets which i need to compare. Both the sheets has two columns i.e "element" and color. Now let's say if sheet A has an element called "x" and color "Red" now sheet B has element "x" and color as "Blue". Then in this case it should return as not matched. It should search for all the "x" elements in sheet "B" and find out the non matched items . Need some help . 
[Sheet A . It creates an extra column with the value of element found in sheet B as found/not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KsYv.png)

[Sheet B . It creates the output after comparison with sheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqsWF.png)

The solutions need to be done in node.js . I am surprise if excel-compare node module will help me.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy after converting both the files to json format